# "memory leak" when using Windows Forms progress bar

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Windows Vista and Visual Studio 2010. I create a Windows Forms Application, drop a text box and a progress bar on the default form, add `progressBar1.Value = 10;` in the button click event handler.

I start debugging the memory usage of the application is 5400k as reported by the task manager, and it's stable as expected. I click on the button, the progress bar value changes to 10, the memory usage of the application grows to 8700k in about 4 and half minutes then stays stable.

Anyone has an explanation for that? Not that it looks critical or anything as it stays stable in the end, but that's weird and I'm curious.

I noticed that when investigating memory usage that goes up to 300 MB for no apparent reason in an application that uses fast moving progress bars.

Edit:

I'm still investigating the second case. But the first case I'm talking about is a plain form with just a progress bar and a button. Here is the source:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 10;
}
```

Comment: A link to another website in my question gets edited and deleted? Are you serious?

Comment: Apparently Bobby thought it had nothing to do with it <whistle/> If you don't agree, just edit it right back in, and perhaps motivate why it deserves a mention :)

Comment: @user755327, @sehe: I have to apologize, I read that as `...that's not about it`. But for my defense, I have to say that the discussion in that forum seemed totally unrelated, because he's looking for a leak in *his encoding code*, not in a control or the framework. If you feel my edit was wrong (which it partly was, sorry), feel free to re-add the link.

Comment: Well, the last paragraph (before the edit) had nothing to do with it. It was just to explain how I ended up looking at that, which might seem odd. Removing it entirely would have been fine, but removing just the link really looked like a "only SO is good enough" attitude to me.

Comment: Didn't refresh and see Bobby's reply before I replied. If you read it all he says it's because of the progress bars somewhere towards the end. But doesn't really matter as it was just to give some context to my question.

Comment: @user755327: As I said, I misread that sentence. I also didn't think that they two were coupled together but the first one was a mere addition to the context. As said, feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net runtime will reserve memory for an application even if it doesn't use it. The memory will appear to be in use, but will be freed if your system starts to go low on free memory.

This may be the case for your application. The runtime reserves memory without it really being used.

Comment: The memory usage goes up only when you change the progress bar value.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up perf-mon and look at .NET memory tickers - bytes in all heaps, bytes in each generation, collections, etc. If that's stable, you're fine.

Comment: It's stable in the end. But going up by 3300k in 4:30 min caused by a change in the progress bar value is weird.

Comment: @user755327: no it's unexpected by you. Weird is expecting computers to do what you expect only :) Garbage collection makes memory usage undeterministic. Heap profiling is a good recommendation

Comment: Exactly sehe. Over time you will need to know what 'normal' looks like so when something abnormal happens, you'll recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

What memory usage are you referring to? Virtual Set means nothing - merely that the heap is getting fragmented over repeated garbage collect runs.

Also, where's the source code for your test? Right now, all I can think is: it must be somewhere else in your own code :)

Answer (score 0):

May be when you are debugging Visual Studio is taking memory not your application.
Try to run your application in release mode (not through Visual Studio) IDE and check for memory

Comment: I tried. It starts at 3400k and goes up to 6800k still in about 4:30 min. Less memory usage because there is no debugging, but still same behaviour.